# How to avoid retrieving relational objects within relational reference loop using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to correctly design the structure of an Api controller method with the following object as a return type:

```
           var obj= new CustomObject
                    {
                        Id = a.Id,
                        stampleProperty= a.stampleProperty,
                        stampleProperty= a.stampleProperty2,
                        B= a.B,
                    };
```

The baseline scenario consists of two objects A and B that have a "Many to Many" relationship as described below:

[image]

```
public class A
{

   public int AId { get; set; }
   public string sampleProperty{ get; set; }        
   public string sampleProperty2{ get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{

   public int BId { get; set; }
   public string sampleProperty3{ get; set; }        
   public string sampleProperty4{ get; set; }
   public int  ComyId { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection A{ get; set; }
   public virtual Comy Comy{ get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** I cannot change the structure of the Database. In addition, I seek the best possible way to retrieve relational B objects from A object, without B's virtual properties of A.

The code that I tried on the controller, although it uses the "LazyLoading" approach, returns embedded type A objects within each associated type B object.

```
var a = db.A.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stampleProperty== stampleProperty);
var obj= new CustomObject
                    {
                        Id = a.AId,
                        sampleProperty= a.sampleProperty,
                        sampleProp= a.sampleProp,
                        B = a.B,
                    };
```

Return:

```
{
 "AId": 
 "sampleProperty":
 "sampleProp":
 "B":[{
      "BId":
      "sampleProperty3":
      "sampleProperty4":
      "ComyId":
      "A":[ **REFERENCE LOOP**  ]
      "ComyId":
      "Comy":{}
     }]
}
```

**Goal:** B objects without Virtual properties of A.

Due to the fact that I am on the process of learning this framework I am looking for the right approach to use these tools by avoiding raw SQL queries and multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating an additional custom object and mapping the fields (either manually or using a framework like AutoMapper).

Applied to your example it could look something like:

```
public class CustomObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string stampleProperty { get; set; }
    public string stampleProperty2 { get; set; }
    public CusomObjectB[] B { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObjectB
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public string sampleProperty3{ get; set; }        
    public string sampleProperty4{ get; set; }
    public int ComyId { get; set; }
}
```

And the usage would look like this:

```
var a = db.A.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stampleProperty== stampleProperty);

var obj= new CustomObjectA
{
    Id = a.AId,
    sampleProperty= a.sampleProperty,
    sampleProp= a.sampleProp,
    B = a.B.Select(b => new CustomObjectB
    {
        BId = b.BId,
        sampleProperty3 = b.sampleProperty3

        //etc...
    }).ToArray()
};
```

It's not necessarily a good idea to return database entities straight from an API for these sorts of reasons (along with some others, such as you may not want third parties consuming your API to be able to see every property in the database).

A common term for this approach is the use of DTOs (Data Transfer Objects). Here's a tutorial from Microsoft where they discuss it further https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5.

Comment: Note: typos left in deliberately to match up with question code examples.